# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, app doesn't run on emulator

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2560012 byte allocation   
with 1668568 free bytes and 1629KB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
```

Runs perfectly on my tablet, but comes up with this error on emulator. Any ideas?

I have tried adding

```xml
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to the manifest but it's a no-go.

Comment: no code, just a shit ton of drawables on xml

Comment: Please make sure drawables are not of higher quality

Comment: What is the resolution of the drawables? I had a problem when I had 5 images with 1000x1000~ish resolution.

Comment: had like 15 drawables at 200x200. resized them all down to 100x100  which cut the filesizes down by 3 quarters. still no go. realized my background was like 1000x1000 reduced that down by 70% and it worked. i have a suspicion that the file sizes are key here and its not just about res

Answer (score 0):

Ok ,so here is details for the same ,
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

```
public class OutOfMemoryError
extends VirtualMachineError
```

Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector. OutOfMemoryError objects may be constructed by the virtual machine as if suppression were disabled and/or the stack trace was not writable.
Ways to solve these error :-
An easy way to solve OutOfMemoryError in java is to increase the maximum heap size by using JVM options "-Xmx512M", this will immediately solve your OutOfMemoryError.
The second way to resolve OutOfMemoryError in Java is rather hard and  comes when you don't have much memory and even after increase maximum heap size you are still getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, in this case, you probably want to profile your application and look for any memory leak.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html#ixzz4EUJfnfac